How to use Navigation Compose new features in Hilt Navigation Compose?
I just read that we can use type safety in Navigation Compose if we update to version 2.8.0. But how about Hilt Navigation Compose? I just upgraded to version 1.2.0 but I didn't find the new Navigation Compose features. When I write navController. Android Studio provides a hint to use navigateBack(), and when I autocomplete, Android Studio complains that such a function doesn't exist. How to use the new features in Hilt Navigation Compose?

I recomment using Compose destinations library for this. It removes all the excess boiler plate code and makes your code slick and easy to read. https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations
